# Bitcoin blockchain verification on download

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain

I would know what does Bitcoin verify when you download a block.

Are the transactions verified too, or not? If they are, will it be the case for their signatures?

Best wishes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends what kind of software you're talking about.

A full node, by definition, verifies all consensus rules for newly received blocks and their transactions, including:

- Proof of work
- Difficulty adjustment
- Subsidy (do miners not print too much money)
- Double spending (do transactions not spend anything already spent)
- Transaction balance (do transactions not spend more than they send)
- Resource limits (block weight limit, op count limits)
- Signature validity
- ...

Other software that interacts with the Bitcoin network may verify whatever it likes - ranging from all of the above, to some subset, or nothing at all and just trusting what other nodes or servers give it.